# Как сделать адаптивный слайдер

Tags: html, css, slider

Как сделать адаптивный слайдер, что бы при уменьшении страницы уменьшался и сам слайдер и картинка в нём?

```js
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide"
    });
});
```

```css
ul{
    list-style: none;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #42c1b0;
}


/*Slider*/

.flexslider {
  max-width: 1290px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 445px;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}

.flexslider .slides img {
  height: auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}

.flex-viewport {
  height: 445px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.loading .flex-viewport {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.carousel li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.flex-direction-nav {
  *height: 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -50px;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -50px;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 10px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 10px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: -1;
}

.flex-pauseplay a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}

.flex-pauseplay a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.flex-pauseplay a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before {}

.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
  position: relative;
  top: -68px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  background: cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #77d3cb;
  cursor: default;
}

.flex-control-thumbs {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}


/* ====================================================================================================================
     * RESPONSIVE
     * ====================================================================================================================*/

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 10px;
  }
}

/*new*/
.first-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.first-slide img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.kofta{
  position: relative;
  left: 205px;
  top: 68px;
  display: flex;
}

.texst {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 580px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 270px;
}

.texst h1{
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3.7em;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    font-weight: 100;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(24, 141, 118);
}

.texst p{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.texst a{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.ghost-button-rounded-corners {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 135px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.ghost-button-rounded-corners:hover,
.ghost-button-rounded-corners:active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
/*end Slider*/
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="first-slide">
        <img class="kofta" src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/16/4c5204c7ef78a0f60adbba872f31239b-full.png">
        <div class="texst">
          <h1>Cowhide<br> Standard Crew</h1>
          <p>White coloured, short-sleeved, printed T-shirt for<br> men by Levi's. This crew-neck T-shirt is made of<br> organic cotton and comes in a regular fit. </p><br>
          <a class="ghost-button-rounded-corners" href="http://mnogoblog.ru/">Shop now</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="kofta" src="http://www.jimmyjazz.com/customfiles/11_06_15_790x200_levis.jpg">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Все таки, чтобы не костылить, на будущее, рекомендую **Swiper** (http://idangero.us/swiper/api/), там при инициализации можно настроить адаптивность, указать на каких разрешениях как отображать слайды. Пример:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.b-catalog-carousel_slider', {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 20,
        pagination: '.b-catalog-carousel_slider-pagination',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        breakpoints: {// настройки для разных разрешений
            768: {
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
                spaceBetween: 8
            },
            991: {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                spaceBetween: 30
            },
            1192: {
                slidesPerView: 3,
                spaceBetween: 20
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\test\style\main.css">
  <script src="D:\test\js\adaptiveMenu.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="testwrap">
    <div id="test">
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x350/00BFFF/FFFFFF?text=1" alt="">
          <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x350/90EE90/FFFFFF?text=2" alt="">
          <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x350/FFA500/FFFFFF?text=3" alt="">
          <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
        </div> <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a> </div>
      <br>
      <div style="text-align:center"> <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```